# Using only SessionAuthentication with django-rest-auth

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a little question.

I'm making website with react, redux and django rest framework. And I'm going to implement authentication using django-rest-auth.

When user login, django-rest-auth return token and session id with headers. I just want to use session id only.

I tried with Postman it works or not. Firstly, login in rest-auth/login with username and password. I got token, I can see sessionid and csrftoken inside cookies tabs.
Then when I tried to logout with headers includes X-CSRFToken: csrftoken value, I could logout successfully. Also I saw "django_session" and "authtoken_token" values are gone in mysql.

Is this workflow ok to authenticate? I mean not using given token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, what is *ok* for you. You are able to use session authentication, but keep in mind, that token auth is enabled (you can disable it in settings).

Comment: How can I disable auth token and use only session authentication? Because django-rest-auth dependents on rest_framework.authtoken, right? Do I need to make custom LoginView that don't return token?

Comment: @Mickey in your settings.py you should have something like this `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    )
}`. You need to remove `TokenAuthentication`. Also from `INSTALLED_APPS` remove `'rest_framework.authtoken'`

Comment: @Mickey - And just an advice, based on my experience. Tokens are very comfortable to use with React+DRF. I don't know, on what project are you working, but I would recommend to think twice before disabling tokens

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. According to your opinion, if I use token for authentication, I need to store it to localStorage, right? I want to use cookie, because I want to access session id before react renders the initial page.

Comment: @Mickey - you _can_ store it in localStorage, its common practice. You also can use cookies, right, but there are some security issues (I'm not very familiar with this). Also there is sessionStorage, but it is almost the same as localStorage

Comment: In [Where to Store Tokens - Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens), they recommend not to store token in localStorage. Is it only about JWT, not token that we are talking about here? Famous websites like Airbnb, Twitter or Kijiji, they are storing token inside cookies. That's why I decided to use session and cookies. But I'm a begginer, could you tell me what choice is good for me. I'm making a classified ads like gumtree, craigslist. In my websites authenticated user will use paypal or stripe to payment.

Comment: @Mickey - even in this article they say about problems with both localStorage _(Browser local storage (or session storage) is not secure. Any data stored there may be vulnerable to cross-site scripting. )_ and cookies _(Cookies can be vulnerable to cross-site request forgery (CSRF or XSRF) attacks.)_. And I don't fully understand, how they suggest to store tokens _(If you have a single-page application (SPA) with no corresponding backend server, your SPA should request new tokens on page load)_ - every time make user authorized?

Comment: @Mickey - anyway, security is a very big topic to discuss it here